Kotlin 2.0 explicit backing field with lazy initialization delegate
How to rewrite the following piece of code to use the new explicit backing field feature of Kotlin 2.0 and keep using the lazy initialization delegate:
private val _viewState: MutableState<UiState> by lazy { mutableStateOf(initialState) }
val viewState: State<UiState> by lazy { _viewState }


Not possible to do that.

@Tenfour04 hmmm, that's unfortunate!

I know this may be a contrived example, but MutableState is a very trivial object. There’s no reason to use lazy for it. Creating the Lazy instance itself (which is done immediately when lazy() is called) is probably equivalent overhead to just directly creating the State.

Why need two lazy? I can understand the first one, but the second line could've been val viewState: State<UiState> get() = _viewState. As correctly noted above lazy creates and object, so it's actually hurting your performance and memory usage in this case.

My main question is about the lazy approach itself, how to do it with the backing field, the type being initialized is irrelevant.
But thank you for the additional note about the overhead.

Delegation is not supported by explicit backing fields. This is mentioned in several places in KEEP.
"Use cases not supported by the explicit backing field feature":

Use cases listed below are not supported to be rewritten with a new feature. However, they are left in the list to provide a more complete picture of pattern use in the wild, as well as to illustrate statistic-driven rationale for decision making.
...
Delegation
It's possible that either backing property (example) or primary property (example) is delegated.
Statistics: backing property delegation found in 2693 files, primary property delegation in 1010 files.

"Design - other restrictions":

Neither property with explicit backing field:

...
nor explicit backing field itself can be delegated (added to Future enhancements)


Delegation is also included in "Future enhancements" section, so it might become possible in the future:

We strive to keep the design simple and uncluttered, so at this point we put aside functionality, which is rarely used or would complicate language too much. Of course, we may revise some decisions in the future based on community feedback. Here is a list of the most obvious future enhancements for the feature:

...
...
Support delegation of explicit backing field or property.


